# ¿Cómo integrar una función sobre los valores de un diccionario?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Soy nuevo en Python y estoy aprendiendo a realizar tareas sencillas. En este ejemplo estoy intentando calcular el salario de un empleado de acuerdo a las horas trabajadas, incluyendo horas extra. La función debe iterar sobre un diccionario que incluye el nombre y las horas que se trabajaron en la semana.

La lista es la siguiente

```
empleados = {'Monica' : 55, 'Patricia': 15, 'Jesus': 32, 'Leonardo': 49}
```

Y mi función para calcular el salario es la siguiente

```
def salario_diario(horas_trabajadas, salario):
    if horas_trabajadas > 40:
      return 40 * salario + ((horas_trabajadas - 40) * salario_extra)
    else:
      return horas_trabajadas * salario

salario = 20
salario_extra = salario * 1.5
```

Lo que no entiendo es cómo integrar a mi función que el parámetro `horas trabajadas` lo obtenga de los `valores` del diccionario `empleados`. Entiendo que debe hacer interar sobre la lista y hacer un cálculo para cada uno de las `llaves` y `valores`; es decir, que tome la `{Monica : 55}` y lo utilice en el cálculo de la función. Esto para todos los `valores`del diccionario.

¿Alguien me puede apoyar explicando como integrarlo a mi función? Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo añada un bucle que itere el diccionario de `empleados` y llame a la función con el valor de las horas trabajadas, el salario y el salario extra.
Para iterar las `llaves` y los `valores` del diccionario use `.items()`

El nuevo código sería:

```py
empleados = {'Monica' : 55, 'Patricia': 15, 'Jesus': 32, 'Leonardo': 49}

def salario_diario(horas_trabajadas, salario, salario_extra):
    if horas_trabajadas > 40:
      return 40 * salario + ((horas_trabajadas - 40) * salario_extra)
    else:
      return horas_trabajadas * salario

for nombre, horas_trabajadas in empleados.items():
  salario = 20
  salario_extra = salario * 1.5
  result = salario_diario(horas_trabajadas, salario, salario_extra)
  print(result)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Estoy empezando en Python y me cuesta trabajo integrar las iteraciones. Tu respuesta me ayudo mucho a entender que debo hacer.

Comment: Me alegra saber que te fue útil. ¡Buena suerte en tu aprendizaje!